# Overloading >> operator and adding a number to a string

Tags: c++

im having trouble getting my function to add numbers to a string. The numbers are from a matrix and are integers. Im trying to parse them to a string formated as {{a,b,c},{d,e,f},{g,h,i}}. Have have implemented the code but when i run it, its blank where the numbers should be and i have no idea why.

My function:

```
    istream& operator>>(istream& in, Matrix& m) {
    vector<int> vec;
    vec = m.getRow(0);
    string matrix = "{";
    in >> matrix;
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++){
        vector<int> vecRow = m.getRow(i);
        matrix+= " {";
        for (int j = 0; j < vec.size(); j++){       
            if(j >=vec.size()-1){
                matrix += vecRow[j];
            }else{
                matrix +=  vecRow[j] + ", " ;
            }
        }
        vecRow.clear();
        matrix+= "}";
        vecRow = m.getRow(i);
    }
    matrix+= " }";

    cout<< matrix<<endl;
    return in;
}
```

Ok so i modified it and now i get no errors, but when i call this function in my tester (cin >> matric) it freezes, nothing happens after it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. Are you trying to parse a string into a `Matrix` object? Or the reverse? (Turn a `Matrix` object into a string.) You never seem to use the `istream& in` parameter.

Comment: Your function never reads anything from the stream.

Comment: @Galik in my tester class, i do cin>>matrix where matrix is and object Matrix

Comment: @Cameron it takes the object Matrix and converts it to a string

Comment: oh and getRow gets all elements in the row(i) of the matrix

Comment: Change `vecRow = m.getRow(i);` to `const vector<int>& vecRow = m.getRow(i);` and remove the vecRow from the beginning of the function or you are copying unnecessary data! I've said three times now!

Comment: the vecRow at the beginning is to get the size of the row for the for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you overload the extraction operator `>>` you need to use the passed in parameter `(std::istream& in, ...)` to get data from the stream **not** the global `std::cin` stream.

A bit like this to get you started:

```
#include<iostream>

struct Matrix {};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Matrix& m)
{
    // input format: {{a,b,c},{d,e,f},{g,h,i}}
    char c;

    // we expect the first char to be '{'
    if(is.get(c) != '{')
        is.setstate(std::ios::failbit); // signal error
    else
    {
        // now process the middle part:
        // {a,b,c},{d,e,f},{g,h,i}

        // ...

        // then check the end brace '}'
        if(is.get(c) != '}')
            is.setstate(std::ios::failbit); // signal error
    }

    return is;
}
```

**But it turns out you are doing the opposite - writing a `Matrix` to the output.**

In this case you need to use the *insert operator* `<<` and pass a `const` reference to your `Matrix`.

Write to the `(std::ostream& os, ...)` parameter a bit like this:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Matrix& m)
{
    // output format: {{a,b,c},{d,e,f},{g,h,i}}

    os << '{'; // initial brace

    // loop on each row
    for(unsigned row = 0; row < m.getSize(); ++row)
    {
        const std::vector<int>& vecRow = m.getRow(row);

        // output one row {a,b,c} item here

        os << '{'; // open row brace

        // loop on each item

        for(unsigned i = 0; i < vecRow.size(); ++i)
        {
            // ,,,
        }

        os << '}'; // close the row
    }

    os << '}'; // close the Matrix

    return os;
}
```

Now when you do `std::cout << m;` your function will be called and the parameter `(std::ostream& os, ...)` will be referring to `std::cout`.

Comment: uhm the input Matrix is in table/matrix form and i have to convert it to the string {a,b,c},{d,e,f},{g,h,i}

Comment: i know i would need to use the ostream operator, but my assignment is to "Overloaded >> operator:  Parses
a string version of a matrix. One example might be in the standard form {{a,b,c},{d,e,f},{g,h,i}}..." So i need to use the >> operator unfortunately.

Comment: Why not `const std::vector<int>& vecRow = m.getRow(row);`

Comment: @a22asin I have given you example code to do both operations.

Comment: You forgot the reference.

Comment: @Galik the istream u showed me above, to me it looks like itt takes in the standard from instead of outputting it? im having a bit of trouble understanding it.

Comment: @a22asin Converting a `Matrix` into a string and "parsing a string" into a `Matrix` are opposite operations. Your assignment is asking for what I did in the *first* example I provided.

Comment: @Galik You don't need to know any API. If by value works, so will const reference.

Comment: Matrix is simply a vector< vector<int> > m

Comment: @Galik i just need a bit of clarification, what am i supposed to initialize c with at the start, it should be "}" right?

Comment: @a22asin You don't need to initialize `c` when you declare it. It gets its value from the stream using `is.get(c)`. Any value you initialize it with will just get thrown away by whatever value gets read from the stream.

Comment: @Galik ok, my only concern is that m isnt in standard format but in  table form. So ur function wouldnt work

Comment: @a22asin My function is not supposed to work. It is incomplete. It is just a guide to help you. It was never my intention to do your homework for you.

Comment: im having quite a bit trouble overloading the >> operator. i think its just that i dont fully understand how >> and cin works. could u please explain it to me please.

Comment: When you do `cin >> m;` it is exactly the same as doing: `operator>>(cin, m);`. You basically call the function `operator>>(cin, m);` passing `cin` and `m` in as the function parameters.

Comment: ok, so what is stored in cin? m, in my case, im assuming is the matrix.

Comment: `cin` is the standard input stream. It "contains" whatever you type in on the keyboard. For this task it is supposed to be the string `{{a,b,c},{d,e,f},{g,h,i}}`.

Comment: ohhhhhhh now i get it